# Hardcoding attributes in django models

Tags: python, django, database-design, django-models

OK here goes, this is one of those questions that makes perfect sense in my head but is difficult to explain properly :) I have a django app where I want to store records for lots of different items of equipment. Each type of equipment will have a custom model to store its attributes, such as `MyEquipment` below. Each type of equipment will also have a 'category', which would be useful to store as an attribute.

```
class Category(models.Model):
    code = models.CharField('Category', max_length=4, unique=True)
    description = models.CharField('Description', max_length=30)
    ...

class MyEquipment(models.Model):
    serial = models.IntegerField()
    ...
```

To save this attribute to my model I could use a foreign key to `Category` but I don't need to because every record in `MyEquipment` must be the same `Category`. So then I thought maybe I could hardcode the `Category` in the `MyEquipment` meta like this:

```
class MyEquipment(models.Model):
    serial = models.IntegerField()
    ...

    class Meta:
        category = Category.objects.get(code='EC')
```

But then this would rely on the `Category` model being populated with data to build the `MyEquipment` model. To me this doesn't seem best practice, using data that may or may not exist to define the structure of another model. Is there a better way I should be using to set which `Category` the `MyEquipment` model is related to?

**EDIT**

Thanks for the discussion below, it's made me realise perhaps I wasn't clear on my original post. So what I want to do is have a way of linking `MyEquipment` to a `Category`. So I can do something like this:

```
>>> from myapp.models import MyEquipment
>>> MyEquipment.CATEGORY
<Category: EC>
```

I want to link the whole model to a `Category`, so I can process each model in different ways in my view depending on which category it is. Having thought about the problem a bit more, I can get this functionality by writing `MyEquipment` like this:

```
class MyEquipment(models.Model):
    CATEGORY = Category.objects.get(code='EC')

    serial = models.IntegerField()
    ...
```

This way works, but is it the best way? I guess the model would do this get operation everytime the class is instantiated? Is there a more efficient method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do this anyway; the Meta class doesn't support arbitrary attributes.

The best thing would be to define this as a property, which you can access via the instance itself. To make it more efficient, you could memoize it on the class.

```
@property
def category(self):
    _category = getattr(self, '_category', None)
    if not _category:
        self.__class__._category = _category = Category.objects.get(code='EC')
    return _category
```

Comment: OK thanks, I haven't come across the @property decorator before. How would I use it in my use case?

Comment: You can just access it directly: `my_equipment_instance.category`.

Comment: I see so I would put this def as part of the `MyEquipment` class definition? This method still relies on the 'EC' record being  in the `Category` model, does this matter? Or is it not worth worrying about?

Comment: Yes you put it in your class. I don't understand your question though; if the category does not exist this will raise an error when it is accessed, but what else would you expect to happen? Why would the category not exist?

Comment: I just thought that when testing the code or before I populate the `Category` model it could cause the building of `MyEquipment` to error. But I guess it would only ever error if I called the category property which is not a big deal.

Comment: Can I access the `category.code` from a `app.MyEquipment` instance using this property method? The reason I wanted to do this is so I can loop through all models in an app and do different things with them in the view based on what category they are. Or can I only get this info when I have an individual `MyEquipment` record instance?

Comment: I don't understand what distinction you're making here.

Answer (score 0):

`but ... every record in MyEquipment must be the same Category`

Then you don't need any relationship. As you said already, every record in MyEquipment are same Category, why do you want to store relation in db?

**UPD:** Solution with model inheritance

```
class Place(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category)
    class Meta:
         abstract = True

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.category = Category.objects.get(name=self.CATEGORY)
        return super(Place, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

class Restaurant(Place):
    ...fields...
    CATEGORY = 'RE'

class Building(Place):
    ...fields...
    CATEGORY = 'BU'
```

Comment: You're right I don't need to store it as a relation, but if I just hardcode something like `CATEGORY = 'EC'` in all my models I thought it would become a bit difficult to manage. I also use the `Category` model elsewhere for proper ForeignKey relationships so it will exist whether I use it with the `MyEquipment` model or not.

Comment: I think you are trying to accomplish different thing, but not sharing whole picture yet. Lets suppose you have `Category` model and `Restaurant` model can only have 'RE' as its Category, `Building` model stores 'BU' as its category and so on. In this case you should create one parent model, lets say `Place`, than inherit Restaurant, Building models from it, by doing this you will have abstraction necessary to build your app, and all of them can point to its `Category`

Comment: So do you mean I should include `Category` as a ForeignKey as part of an abstract base class linked to the `Restaurant` and `Building` models? Using that I would still have to write some custom code to set the `Category` each time I add a `Restaurant` or `Building` wouldn't I? If so using the answer above method seems better to me

Comment: yes you would do, but everything has its cost you can override `save()` method from each inherited model and put there your category `instance.category = 'RE'` `instance.category = 'BU'` and so on, then you should correctly handle `update` method from Queryset